# Removing String from the column in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, coalesce

After executing the R code, the values I got in the column of dataframe are:

1. 25 July 2012 bet
2. 22 June 2015 bet
3. 09 April 2015 be
4. 14 November 2016

   I want only the dates, How can I remove "bet", "be" from the values?

I am using the below code to extract the above values from the text document:

coalesce((substr((stringr::str_match(text, "ISDA Master Agreement dated as of (.*) ")[, 2]),1,16)),(substr((stringr::str_match(text, "ISDA Master Agreement dated as of (.*) ")[, 2]),1,13)))

If I swipe the coalesce arguements, then the 4th value gets truncated.

I am ok with the code, but while cleaning, how should I remove the "bet","be"?

Answer (score 2):

I am far away from being a regex expert, but here goes a [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) way of doing what you want:

```r
library(tidyverse, verbose = F)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~V1,                ~V2,
   1L, "25 July 2012 bet",
   2L, "22 June 2015 bet",
   3L, "09 April 2015 be",
   4L, "14 November 2016"
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = str_replace(V2, pattern = "[:space:]be.*", replacement = ""))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      V1 V2              
#>   <int> <chr>           
#> 1     1 25 July 2012    
#> 2     2 22 June 2015    
#> 3     3 09 April 2015   
#> 4     4 14 November 2016
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to remove whitespace and everything  with `"be"`

```
sub("\\s+be.*", "", c("25 July 2012 bet", "09 April 2015 be"))
#[1] "25 July 2012"  "09 April 2015"
```

Comment: If I need to use to use it for other types, just need to change the "be" with the values needed to be removed from the string output?

Comment: Yes, if it has the same structure as shown here. It would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `lubridate` you can strip away the excess text after the date:

```
library(lubridate)

test_strings <- c("25 July 2012 bet", "09 April 2015 be")

dmy(test_strings)

[1] "2012-07-25" "2015-04-09"
```